# Android ImageView: height, width change in Samsung handsets after remote image loading

Tags: android, android-image

I've an android application where ImageView load a remote image of size 60X275 in AsyncTask. I test this application in many handset like HTC, Sony E, Samsung etc. I've an observation that, Samsung handset (tested on- Galaxy y, SIII)  resize the actual image height weight. Like in Galaxy y I found the size 80X367, Galaxy SIII resize it to- 30X138.

I'm in serious trouble  with Samsung handset for my application. My ImageView declaration in XML file is-

```
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/banner" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_below="@id/name"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
```

And AsycTask doing the below-

```
private Drawable ImageOperation(String url) {
    Drawable d = null;
    try {
        URL imageurl = new URL(url);
        InputStream is = (InputStream) imageurl.getContent();
        d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

Drawable image = ImageOperation(fileName);  

imgView.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
```

Please suggest me ASAP if possible as I'm in great exigency.

Comment: You do not say what problem you are having.  If it is simply resizing, then of course it will since you use wrap_content for height.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: so can you please suggest what should I use to display the original image in the ImageView as source height weight? ImageView height= fill_parent is not possible to use.